# How do I configure my server to display a Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

So, I've tried installing the Crystal Reports runtime on my server as well as copy all the DLL's from our old server to the new server.  I copied my application over, and it's telling me:

Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=blahblahblah' or one of its dependencies.

How do I get that???  The reference is in the GAC on the old server, but I can't find the DLL for that anywhere.

When you set up a new server, what exactly needs to happen to ready the new web server to be able to display Crystal Reports?  I can not believe it is this difficult to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

1) This error is occured because of version change of crystal report. Install Crystal Decesion pack 2005 as well as 2008 for 64 bit and 32 bit.

2) Set your DSN 32 bit and 64 bit both.

3) once try with set your application in classic pool.